# how to call the TabIntent Explicitly?

Tags: android

I have a home screen in my app which has 3 tabs A,B,C. the tab C has screen X which goes to other 2 Screens Y and Z in the order Y->Z. From Screen Z I am calling the Screen X which is inside the Tab. When the screen Z is called it is loading the screen properly but I am not getting the Tab which with the Screen X. How can I get the TabIntent when I am calling a Screen which is attached to the Tab. please help me out in doing this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Dont use simply Activity instead use ActivityGroup for activities X,Y,Z.

Since whenever you are switching from Activity X to Y it creates a new Task & displays that

new  Actvity.

Here are some link please go through it.

http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/

http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Best Regards,
~Anup

Comment: hi Anup! I am very new to android. Can u please explain me a bit how can I do that.

Comment: Hi Richa, you want to display three activities in the same tab, is it correct please confirm?

Comment: No, Actually I have only 1 activity in my tab that is the X screen. when I click on that tab it goes to Screen X. From screen X ,I can go to Screen Y and then From Screen Y I can go to screen Z. Yand Z are not inside the tab. when from Screen Z I am calling the Screen X which was inside the Tab, the Screen is being loaded but without the Tab. how can I get the tab?

Comment: ok I got it, first of all there is no concept like screen in android you want to say View or Activity please confirm? as far as your problem is concern what are you doing when switching back from y to X. I mean are you creating X again. Could you please post your some code so that i can get an idea.

Comment: the order of switching is like this... X->Y , Y->Z and then Z->X.

Comment: could you please post some of your code, since I didn't get what is mean by Screen.

Comment: Oh I am very Sorry!! It's Activity.(Here X is my Activity)  
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setClass(this,X.class);  
startActivity(intent);

Comment: ok Here we go, use ActivityGroup which comprises with no of Activities